# Custom Cell Appearance in GridView change event

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am disabling a checkbox column in a XtraGrid GridView with the following code (works as expected). Got the code from this post https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q423605:

[image: Disabled checkbox]

```
    private void GridViewWeeklyPlan_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "Ignore")
        {
            CheckEditViewInfo viewInfo = ((GridCellInfo)e.Cell).ViewInfo as CheckEditViewInfo;
            viewInfo.CheckInfo.State = DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.ObjectState.Disabled;
        }
    }
```

**ISSUE**

I want to enable the checkbox again when a certain column changes and has a value. This is where I am stuck and I thought I can change it in the GridView's CellValueChanged event, but I do not know how to reference the cell/column for the row:

[image: Change the checkbox when column has value]

```
    private void GridViewWeeklyPlan_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName != "Reason") return;


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()))
        {
            //Make sure the checkbox is disabled again
        }
        else
        {
            //Enable the checkbox to allow user to select it
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh a cell in the Ignore column. You can do this by calling the [GridView.RefreshRowCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RefreshRowCelltopic) method. To identify a row that you need to refresh, the *CellValueChanged* event provides the *e.RowHandle* parameter.

```
private void GridViewWeeklyPlan_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName != "Reason") return;
        GridView view = (GridView)sender;   
        view.RefreshRowCell(e.RowHandle, view.Columns["Ignore"]);

    }
```

The *CustomDrawCell* event will be raised again to update the cell appearance.